# org-mode tables: refer to a field in a table from formula in another table

Tags: emacs, org-mode, tabular

I'm planning the project with org-mode. I have several tables with some calculations.
What do I need is the way to create the table that summarizes the data from previous tables.

Is there a way to refer to the values of the fields between tables?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, this is explained in te org-mode [manual for references](http://orgmode.org/manual/References.html) under `remote references`.